# CSS Display/Hide Methods

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just fixed this issue but I am still puzzled on why I was having trouble. When trying to hide a div I tried to use this code:

```
<div id = myDiv></div>

function MyFunction(){
    $('#myDiv').css("display", "none");
}
```

That code would not work when trying to hide the div, but this will

```
  function MyFunction(){
    $('#myDiv').hide();
}
```

I wanted to know what the difference was between each of these methods, and why one would work while the other did not.

Comment: did you have an !important key in your css file?

Comment: No, would that be the issue that would cause .css not to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem

```
<div id = myDiv></div>
```

You have to do like this

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Since both .hide() and .css() will add "display: none" to your element, the above code is the only thing I could think of. Always use "" with attributes.

Comment: While I agree it definitely needs to be fixed, `<div id = myDiv>` does seem to work in browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hgm8/

Comment: Yeah, probably.. Does it work in all browsers or just the one and only IE? :)

Answer (score 0):

Copied out exactly how you have it, the code doesn't work, but you might not have meant it all literally.  Just in case, it should be something like (notice the script block and the correct spacing and quotation on the div tag):

```
<div id="myDiv">hello world</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction(){
        $('#myDiv').css("display", "none");
    }
</script>
```

So if that wasn't your problem, there must be something else going on on the page somewhere that's breaking your html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change the css directly, it is better practice to add and remove a class that contains the display declarations you want.

So

```
$('#myDiv').addClass('hidden');
```

adds

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

I find this method to be much more reliable and flexible.